# Node.js is not saving user session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies

I've worked a lot with nodejs in building session systems but for some reason this simply is not working and I can't figure out why, I don't know if I'm missing something.

Here is the code (I'm still testing some things so the code is not ideal at all but should be functional for the session):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var io_session = require("express-socket.io-session");
var e_session = require("express-session");

var MemoryStore = e_session.MemoryStore;

var enableCORS = function(req, res, next) {

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, *');

        // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    };
};

var e_session = e_session({
    secret: "eaifgneaifiea30r3jafeaofoeakfoeak",
    store: new MemoryStore(),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { 
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 24*60*60*1000 //1 minute
   } 
});


app.use(function(req, res, next) {      
  ///console.log('Current User:', req);
  next();
});

app.use(e_session);
app.use(enableCORS);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.post("/TEST_start_login",function(req,res){

    console.log("starting login");

    req.session.alias = ["lol"];
    req.session.user = "WTF";

    console.log("req.session:",req.session);

    to_send = JSON.stringify(returnValues("success","login_registered",{}));

    res.send(to_send);

});

app.post("/TEST_test_login",function(req,res){

    console.log("SESSION:",req.session);
    res.status(200).send();

});
```

As you can see in the last two methods I save two variables to the session so I can test if the user is logged in or not.

Here is my javascript in the frontend that tests for this:

```
function sendToServer (object,type,callback,url) {

    if(url == undefined) {
        url = "";
    }

    if(typeof type == undefined) {
        type = "POST";
    }

     $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080'+url,
                type: type,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(object),
                success: callback

            });
}

function login() {

    var data = {}

    sendToServer(data,"POST",function(data) {

        //return
        data = JSON.parse(data);

        console.log("returned from login:",data);

    },"/TEST_start_login");

}

function checkSession() {

    var data = {}

    sendToServer(data,"POST",function(data) {

        console.log("returned from login:",data);

    },"/TEST_test_login");

}
```

And here is the output int he server of executing `login` and `checkSession`:

login:

> req.session: Session {   cookie:     { path: '/',
>        _expires: 2017-05-07T16:32:43.377Z,
>        originalMaxAge: 86400000,
>        httpOnly: true,
>        secure: false },   alias: [ 'lol' ],   user: 'WTF' }

Variables 'alias' and 'user' are set on session.

check_session:

> SESSION: Session {   cookie:     { path: '/',
>        _expires: 2017-05-07T16:32:45.547Z,
>        originalMaxAge: 86400000,
>        httpOnly: true,
>        secure: false } }

as you can see, going through 'TEST_test_login' route in nodejs no longer shows the variables...

I really am not understanding why this is happening. Can someone please help me figuring this out?

Thank you very much

Comment: Try adding `xhrFields : { withCredentials: true }` to the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call.

Comment: I don't see anywhere you're calling `req.session.save()` after modifying the session object.

Comment: @jfriend00 that's usually not necessary (see [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#sessionsavecallback)).

Comment: @robertklep - I've found it to be necessary in my own testing with the memory store.

Comment: @jfriend00 interesting, I always thought `MemoryStore` didn't require an explicit save because all it does it update an in-memory object when the session is set/changed.

Comment: @robertklep - yeah, that's what you would think, but whenever I've played with it, it didn't save unless I explicitly called `.save()`.

Comment: @robertklep both solutions do not work... I'm getting quite desperate, I really don't understand why... Do you have any other idea? Did you skim well through my code? :(

Comment: @jfriend00 check my previous comment here (as I cannot mention two users in one comment)

Comment: @Fane the code works as-is, when I test it locally. It sounds like the client isn't sending the cookie along with the request, so start looking in your browser's dev tools to follow the requests and responses, and see a) if the initial response contains a valid cookie, b) if the browser stores the cookie and c) if the subsequent request to `/TEST_test_login` contains the cookie in the `Cookie` header.